# Algorithm to establish ordering amongst a set of items

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph-theory

I have a set of students (referred to as items in the title for generality). Amongst these students, some have a reputation for being rambunctious. We are told about a set of hate relationships of the form 'i hates j'. 'i hates j' does **not** imply 'j hates i'. We are supposed to arrange the students in rows (front most row numbered 1) in a way such that if 'i hates j' then i should be put in a row that is **strictly** lesser numbered than that of j (in other words: in some row that is in front of j's row) so that i doesn't throw anything at j (Turning back is not allowed). What would be an efficient algorithm to find the minimum number of rows needed (each row need not have the same number of students)?

We will make the following assumptions:

1) If we model this as a directed graph, there are no cycles in the graph. The most basic cycle would be: if 'i hates j' is true, 'j hates i' is false. Because otherwise, I think the ordering would become impossible.

2) Every student in the group is at least hated by one other student OR at least hates one other student. Of course, there would be students who are both hated by some and who in turn hate other students. This means that there are no stray students who don't form part of the graph.

**Update:** I have already thought of constructing a directed graph with i --> j if 'i hates j and doing topological sorting. However, since the general topological sort would suit better if I had to line all the students in a single line. Since there is a variation of the rows here, I am trying to figure out how to factor in the change into topological sort so it gives me what I want.

When you answer, please state the complexity of your solution. If anybody is giving code and you don't mind the language, then I'd prefer Java but of course any other language is just as fine.

JFYI This is not for any kind of homework (I am not a student btw :)).

Comment: If this isn't homework, sure is a strange problem... :-)

Comment: Assumption 2. is false. If no one hate no one, you can put everyone in the same row.

Comment: @Josh G: I encountered this problem while I was going through some graphs slides and since the material was from an academic setting, it kind of explains the "strangeness".

Comment: @vartec: Yes, you are right. But I feel that doesn't make anything in the assumption false. By that point, I meant to say that no node in the graph is unconnected. As in all students form part of the single connected graph. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @Skylark: Now it makes sense... :-). Definitely not a real problem per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from a project management theory (or scheduling theory, I don't know the exact term). There the task is about sorting jobs (vertex is a job, arc is a job order relationship).

Obviously we have some connected oriented graph without loops. There is an arc from vertex `a` to vertex `b` if and only if `a` hates `b`. Let's assume there is a source (without incoming arcs) and destination (without outgoing arcs) vertex. If that is not the case, just add imaginary ones. Now we want to find length of a longest path from source to destination (it will be number of rows - 1, but mind the imaginary verteces).

We will define vertex rank (`r[v]`) as number of arcs in a longest path between source and this vertex `v`. Obviously we want to know `r[destination]`. Algorithm for finding rank:

```
0) r_0[v] := 0  for all verteces v
repeat
t) r_t[end(j)] := max( r_{t-1}[end(j)], r_{t-1}[start(j)] + 1 )  for all arcs j
until for all arcs j r_{t+1}[end(j)] = r_t[end(j)]    // i.e. no changes on this iteration
```

On each step at least one vertex increases its rank. Therefore in this form complexity is **`O(n^3)`**.

By the way, this algorithm also gives you student distribution among rows. Just group students by their respective ranks.

**Edit:** Another code with the same idea. Possibly it is better understandable.

```
# Python
# V is a list of vertex indices, let it be something like V = range(N)
# source has index 0, destination has index N-1
# E is a list of edges, i.e. tuples of the form (start vertex, end vertex)
R = [0] * len(V)
do:
    changes = False
    for e in E:
        if R[e[1]] < R[e[0]] + 1:
            changes = True
            R[e[1]] = R[e[0]] + 1
while changes
# The answer is derived from value of R[N-1]
```

Of course this is the simplest implementation. It can be optimized, and time estimate can be better.

**Edit2:** obvious optimization - update only verteces adjacent to those that were updated on the previous step. I.e. introduce a queue with verteces whose rank was updated. Also for edge storing one should use adjacency lists. With such optimization complexity would be **`O(N^2)`**. Indeed, each vertex may appear in the queue at most `rank` times. But vertex rank never exceeds `N` - number of verteces. Therefore total number of algorithm steps will not exceed **`O(N^2)`**.

Comment: Hi, is there a possibility I can get some help understanding your code? It looks a little exotic for me to grasp it properly. Some kind of a pseudo code maybe?

Comment: Yep, it's kind of pseudocode. Actually I wanted to express it more like a mathematical one. `For all` there is for universal quantifier. 

So the idea is just to spread the maximum possible rank value through the verteces.

Comment: This is not O(N^2) if N = number of students because |E| can be O(N^2), so you get O(N^3).

Comment: Oops, yes, you are right, antti.huima. I was probably bearing in mind some optimization. Corrected the mistake and added optimization description.

Comment: I couldn't access my net yesterday. Thanks for that dragonfly.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me that you need to investigate [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort).

Answer (score 2):

This problem is basically another way to put the [longest path in a directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) problem. The number of rows is actually number of nodes in path (number of edges + 1).

Assuming the graph is [acyclic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), the solution is [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort). 
Acyclic is a bit stronger the your assumption 1. Not only A -> B and B -> A is invalid. Also A -> B,  B -> C, C -> A and any cycle of any length.

HINT: the question is **how many rows** are needed, not which student in which row. The answer to the question is the length of the longest path.

Comment: His requirement is different I believe... he wants as many rows as possible.

Comment: "minimum number of rows needed"

Comment: Yes, I want minimum rows, as less as possible. Vartec, thanks for the correction in the assumption 2. I am going to edit the question again.

Comment: @Skylark: Per Douglas is comment then... Does that mean that a student must actually be in FRONT of a student he hates? Otherwise the smallest number of rows is always 1 because no is BEHIND anyone he hates.

Comment: @Josh G. Hmm... you are right. A student must be in any of the rows in front the other student he hates. However, if A hates B or vice versa, both can't be in the same row.

Comment: I think that's what meant by the diameter of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Essentailly the important thing in assumption #1 is that there must not be any cycles in this graph. If there are any cycles you can't solve this problem.

I would start by seating all of the students that do not hate any other students in the back row. Then you can seat the students who hate these students in the next row and etc.

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows is the length of the longest path in the directed graph, plus one. As a limit case, if there is no hate relationship everyone can fit on the same row.

To allocate the rows, put everyone who is not hated by anyone else on the row one. These are the "roots" of your graph. Everyone else is put on row N + 1 if N is the length of the longest path from any of the roots to that person (this path is of length one at least).

A simple O(N^3) algorithm is the following:

```
S = set of students
for s in S: s.row = -1        # initialize row field
rownum = 0                    # start from first row below
flag = true                   # when to finish
while (flag):
  rownum = rownum + 1         # proceed to next row
  flag = false
  for s in S:
    if (s.row != -1) continue # already allocated
    ok = true
    foreach q in S:
      # Check if there is student q who will sit
      # on this or later row who hates s
      if ((q.row == -1 or q.row = rownum)
          and s hated by q) ok = false; break
    if (ok):                  # can put s here
      s.row = rownum
      flag = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer = 1 row.

Put all students in the same row.

Actually that might not solve the question as stated - lesser row, rather than equal row...

1. Put all students in row 1
2. For each hate relation, put the not-hating student in a row behind the hating student
3. Iterate till you have no activity, or iterate Num(relation) times.

But I'm sure there are better algorithms - look at acyclic graphs.

Comment: "in a way such that if 'i hates j' then i should be put in a row that _is lesser_ numbered than that of j "

Answer (score 0):

Construct a relationship graph where i hates j will have a directed edge from i to j. So end result is a directed graph. It should be a DAG otherwise no solutions as it's not possible to resolve circular hate relations ship.

Now simply do a DFS search and during the post node callbacks, means the once the DFS of all the children are done and before returning from the DFS call to this node, simply check the row number of all the children and assign the row number of this node as row max row of the child +  1. Incase if there is some one who doesn't hate anyone basically node with no adjacency list simply assign him row 0.

Once all the nodes are processed reverse the row numbers. This should be easy as this is just about finding the max and assigning the row numbers as max-already assigned row numbers.

Here is the sample code.

```
postNodeCb( graph g, int node )
{
    if ( /* No adj list */ )
        row[ node ] = 0;
    else
        row[ node ] = max( row number of all children ) + 1;
}

main()
{
.
.

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_VER; i++ )
        if ( !visited[ i ] )
            graphTraverseDfs( g, i );`enter code here`
.
.
}
```